# "Apply Pose as Rest Pose" my model become mess

Tags: animation

I use auto-rig pro to rig my cat in a standing pose.[image] When I finish the rig, pose my cat to sit as a default pose. So I use App-Apply Pose as Rest Pose.[image] However, my cat become this.[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you apply the pose it doesn't align automatically the mesh with the new pose, the mesh will simply come back to its default shape and it will be misaligned with the new pose. In order to align the mesh with the armature new pose: Pose the armature, select the mesh, duplicate its *Armature* modifier, apply it, then select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Pose as Rest Pose*.

Comment: can you more details? please

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it makes it more understandable?